# About the definition of the function field of a quasi-projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi projective variety. The function field of $X$, $k(X)$, is defined as $k(X\cap U)$ where $U$ is **any** affine open subset of $X$ and $k(U)$ is the function field of the affine variety, which is well defined.

By question is, how to show that $k(X)$ is independent of the choice of $U$?

Comment: By intersecting two of them.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubhA, sorry still confused. Could you provide some more detail?

Comment: If $U, V$ are affine and $V \subset U$, then $k(V)=k(U)$. Now suppose that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are any nonempty affine open subsets of $X$. Then $U_1 \cap U_2$ is an affine open subset of both $U_1$ and $U_2$, so $k(U_1)=k(U_1 \cap U_2)=k(U_2)$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, I think by 'affine' you mean 'affine open', could you explain more why $V\subset U$ implies $k(V)=k(U)$? In fact I am not sure about the definition of function field of a affine open variety. Is defined as the function field of the affine variety to which it is isomorphic? If so, I still can't get your statement.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant to write $V \subset U$ open affine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a rational function on an irreducible algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$ is an equivalence class of morphisms $U\to k$, where $U$ is an open subset of $X$. We say that two morphisms $U\to k$ and $U'\to k$ are the same if they coincide on the intersection.

With this definition, you see that the field of rational functions is the same if your restrict to an open subset. You can thus take an open affine subset, and look at it on this.

What is good with affine algebraic varieties, is that they are the Spectrum of a ring $A$ and that regular functions correspond to elements of $A$. The variety is irreducible if and only if the ring $A$ is integral, and in this case you can check with the above definition that rational functions are just elements of the field of fractions of $A$. Hence, looking at affine open subsets is interesting as you can compute easily the field of rational functions.

Moreover, taking the above definition, you directly see that the choice is independent of the open subset, and thus of the affine open subset.

Comment: Hi, thanks, (sorry I am new to AG and confused about a bunch of definitions...) what is the relation between $\mathcal{O}(U)$ and $k(U)$? In the note I am reading only the definition of function field of an affine (Zariski-closed) variety is given. However, here when u say $U$ being affine, I think it means $U$ is isomorphic to an Zariski-closed variety. Then is $k(U)$ defined as the function field of that Zariski-closed variety?

Comment: I tried to explain it in another way. I hope that it is clearer. Note that $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is the set of regular functions and $k(U)$ is the set of rational functions (defined over an open subset), so $\mathcal{O}(U)\subset k(U)$ and if $U$ is affine and irreducible then $k(U)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}(U)$.

Comment: You are welcome.